# Prerequisite in advanced group theory in Fraleigh

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Anyone familiar with Fraleigh's A First Course in Abstract Algebra 7th ed? I'm using it in my self-study of algebra. The first three chapters (Groups and Subgroups, Permutations-Cosets-Direct Products, Homomorphisms and Factor Groups) tackle about group theory. Chapter 4 is "Rings and Field", Chapter 5 "Ideals and Factor Rings", and Chapter 6 "Extension Fields".

I already finished the first 3 chapters, but I don't want to proceed with rings yet. Can I jump into Chapter 7 which is "Advanced Group Theory" and to Chapter 8 "Groups in Topology" (I only finished Chapter 1 and 2 of Munkres' Topology)?

Or is there an advantage of studying the basics of rings first before delving into more advanced topics of group theory?

Comment: Some books (like Gallian) cover almost everything about groups first, then rings, then fields. In my view, it depends on how you want to go.

Comment: I don't have it on hand, but my memory is that Chapter 7 does not depend on the rings/fields material (I never learned or taught out of Chapter 8, so I won't comment on that). In fact, the 8th edition moves Ch. 7 to directly after Ch. 3 (and eliminates Ch. 8). You might check whether there is a graph of chapter dependencies in the preface!

Answer (score 2):

The table of dependencies (p. xiii) indicates that Chapter VII (Sections 34-40) depends only on Sections 1-16 (Chapters I-III) (and only Sections 36-37 use Section 16, and nothing depends on Section 17). Chapter VIII (Sections 41-44) depends only on Sections 1-15 and 38.

Why put this material so deep into the book? Some (but not all) math departments want to include some ring theory in their first semester abstract algebra course, so that a student who takes only one course will leave with some exposure to rings.